# Debian jessie upgrade OpenSSH server to latest

Tags: ssh, debian-jessie

I have a Debian 8 server for a customer that is failing a PCI scan, presumably running:
`nmap -p 22 -sV customer.edu`

which returns

`22/tcp open  ssh     OpenSSH 6.7p1 Debian 5+deb8u7`

This should be easy, given my /etc/apt/sources.list is this:

```
deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian jessie main
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian jessie main
deb http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian-security/ jessie/updates main
deb-src http://mirror.rackspace.com/debian-security/ jessie/updates main
deb http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb-src http://packages.dotdeb.org jessie all
deb http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb-src http://ftp.us.debian.org/debian/ jessie main contrib non-free
deb http://ftp.debian.org/debian jessie-backports main
deb http://security.debian.org/ jessie/updates main contrib non-free
```

`sudo apt-get upgrade openssh-server` returns:

`Calculating upgrade... openssh-server is already the newest version.`

Is there a better way to get the latest OpenSSH server?

I attempted to download it, install its OpenSSL 1.0.2-stable dependency in /usr/local/ but having serious troubles with it failing.

Are my choices to find a better source in apt-get, or attempt to install it and its OpenSSL dependency in /usr/local and manually point systemctl to those binaries?

Comment: You probably should be looking at upgrading to stretch.

Comment: From what I researched, an in-place upgrade is not advised, but rather a new Debian stretch install and migrate our apps to it. Would you agree?

Comment: Depends on what you are running and how well managed the system is.  I have upgraded some systems in place without issue.  Though I also have a well tested backup systems and can easily revert if things go wrong.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> failing a PCI scan

Document for your auditor the version of the **package** installed. Reference security updates regarding OpenSSH, in this case [from Debian](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/openssh). Possibly cross reference relevant CVEs.

Parsing a version number is fragile. Stable distros generally do not upgrade the version, but apply their own patches.

Comment: Yes, this release resolves most of the PCI scan. Except one failure reports "SSH server is using a small public key". Searching suggests this was issue prior to OpenSSH 7. Since your link is listing vulnerabilities, it's unclear if patches have resolved this complaint?

Comment: That is for you to determine comparing the rationale from the audit  to change log and patches of the openssh package you are using. If you have issues with this, ask another question.

Answer (score -3):

I originally published this script here  [install-newer-openssh](https://github.com/eduardolucioac/install-newer-openssh) .
Then the most updated version will be there! 
However, to make it easier I transcribe it here...

### PLUS!

A **SEVERE VULNERABILITY** (CVE-2023-38408) has been discovered in OpenSSH in versions prior to 9.3p2 which is the case for virtually all server Linux distros. CVE-2023-38408 is a vulnerability that allows remote code execution and is present in the SSH agent forwarding feature, especially against "PKCS#11" providers. Leveraging SSH agent support of "PKCS#11" under specific conditions allows attackers to execute remote code through a forwarded agent socket.

**So it's important to update the OpenSSH Service in use on your server to a newer version!**

**MORE INFORMATION:** https://github.com/kali-mx/CVE-2023-38408 , https://tryhackme.com/room/cve202338408 , https://nvd.nist.gov/vuln/detail/CVE-2023-38408 .

---

## OpenSSH Service - Install a newer version (Debian)

### Introduction

Using a OpenSSH service newer version (9.4 at the time of this guide) is easy and crucial for security.

We will install a OpenSSH service newer version while keeping and disabling the one installed by the package manager (Debian official repositories).

Tested on Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye).

**NOTE:** For easier understanding, we will refer to the version installed by the package manager (Debian official repositories) as the OpenSSH service repo version.

**IMPORTANT:** Installing a OpenSSH service newer version alongside the OpenSSH service repo version is recommended because components of the OpenSSH service repo version are used by other components and packages, and its absence can be a source of problems.

### Install the required packages

Install the necessary packages to build and run the OpenSSH service newer version...

```
apt -y install autoconf
apt -y install build-essential
apt -y install cmake
apt -y install libssh-dev
apt -y install libtool
apt -y install netcat
apt -y install wget
```

### Download and build the OpenSSH service newer version

Commands to download and build...

```
wget https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/openssh-9.4p1.tar.gz
OPENSSH_VER="9.4p1"
tar -xvf openssh-${OPENSSH_VER}.tar.gz
cd openssh-${OPENSSH_VER}
./configure --prefix=/opt/openssh-${OPENSSH_VER}
make
make install
cd ..
rm -rf openssh-${OPENSSH_VER}.tar.gz
```

**TIP:** OpenSSH service newer versions can be found at https://cdn.openbsd.org/pub/OpenBSD/OpenSSH/portable/ .

**IMPORTANT:** You should use a *portable* version.

Create a symbolic link (*symbolic link*) so that we can update the OpenSSH service more easily in the future, reusing some configurations...

```
ln -s /opt/openssh-${OPENSSH_VER} /opt/openssh-latest
```

### Change the OpenSSH service repo version configuration

Change the OpenSSH service repo version port in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` configuration file by changing the "#Port 22" parameter to "Port 2222", for example.

**NOTE:** The configuration file for the OpenSSH service newer version will be in the path `/opt/openssh-latest/etc/sshd_config`.

### Create the default environment file for the OpenSSH service newer version

Commands to create the default environment file and a folder for it...

```
mkdir -p "/opt/openssh-latest/default"
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
# Default settings for OpenSSH Server.

# Options to pass to sshd.
SSHD_OPTS=

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" > '/opt/openssh-latest/default/ssh'
```

### Create service configuration files (systemd)

Commands to create the "ssh-latest.service" file...

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=network.target auditd.service
ConditionPathExists=!/opt/openssh-latest/etc/sshd_not_to_be_r

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/opt/openssh-latest/default/ssh
ExecStartPre=/opt/openssh-latest/sbin/sshd -t
ExecStart=/opt/openssh-latest/sbin/sshd -D $SSHD_OPTS
ExecReload=/opt/openssh-latest/sbin/sshd -t
ExecReload=/bin/kill -HUP $MAINPID
KillMode=process
Restart=on-failure
RestartPreventExitStatus=255
Type=exec
RuntimeDirectory=sshd-latest
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
Alias=sshd-latest.service

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" > "/usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh-latest.service"
```

Commands to create the "ssh-latest@.service" file...

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server per-connection daemon
Documentation=man:sshd(8) man:sshd_config(5)
After=auditd.service

[Service]
EnvironmentFile=-/opt/openssh-latest/default/ssh
ExecStart=/opt/openssh-latest/sbin/sshd -i $SSHD_OPTS
StandardInput=socket
RuntimeDirectory=sshd-latest
RuntimeDirectoryMode=0755

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" > "/usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh-latest@.service"
```

Commands to create the "ssh-latest.socket" file...

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
[Unit]
Description=OpenBSD Secure Shell server socket
Before=ssh-latest.service
Conflicts=ssh-latest.service
ConditionPathExists=!/opt/openssh-latest/etc/sshd_not_to_be_r

[Socket]
ListenStream=22
Accept=yes

[Install]
WantedBy=sockets.target

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" > "/usr/lib/systemd/system/ssh-latest.socket"
```

Commands to create the "rescue-ssh-latest.target" file...

```
read -r -d '' FILE_CONTENT << 'HEREDOC'
BEGIN
[Unit]
Description=Rescue with network and ssh
Documentation=man:systemd.special(7)
Requires=network-online.target ssh-latest.service
After=network-online.target ssh-latest.service
AllowIsolate=yes

END
HEREDOC
echo -n "${FILE_CONTENT:6:-3}" > "/usr/lib/systemd/system/rescue-ssh-latest.target"
```

### Service configurations (systemd)

Disable the OpenSSH service repo version...

```
systemctl disable ssh.service
systemctl disable ssh.socket
```

Enable the OpenSSH service newer version...

```
systemctl enable ssh-latest.service
systemctl enable ssh-latest.socket
```

Reboot your system...

```
reboot
```

### Confirm the version of the OpenSSH service newer version

Confirm the version via the binary...

```
/opt/openssh-latest/bin/ssh -V
```

Confirm the version via the service...

```
echo | nc 127.0.0.1 22
```

[Ref(s).: https://gist.github.com/jtmoon79/745e6df63dd14b9f2d17a662179e953a ]

```
  .~.  Have fun! =D
  /V\  
 // \\ Tux
/(   )\
 ^`~'^
```

Comment: This advice is **DANGEROUS** as replacing the packaged version from the official repositories with a self-built one **disables automatic updates**.

Comment: For the CVE-2023-38408: monitor the [Debian security tracker](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2023-38408); it will be *backported* soon, as explained in the accepted answer.

Comment: Also, while waiting for the patch, it is possible to mitigate the risks from this vulnerability: "Restrict PKCS#11 providers: Configure OpenSSH to allow only specific and trusted PKCS#11 providers. By limiting the use of PKCS#11 providers to known and verified sources, you can reduce the potential attack surface and minimize the risk of exploitation." (From [How to fix CVE-2023-38408 in OpenSSH](https://vulcan.io/blog/how-to-fix-cve-2023-38408-in-openssh/).)

Comment: @EsaJokinen The official repositories version is kept installed, just disabled.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Interestingly your reference cites "**Upgrade to OpenSSH 9.3p2 or later:** Upgrading to the latest version of OpenSSH is crucial as it includes critical patches to mitigate the vulnerability. Ensure that all relevant systems and servers are promptly updated to the recommended version or a higher one. ". 

Comment: Yes, and it also says that: "The vulnerability lies in the SSH-agent’s source code, enabling a remote attacker with access to the remote server where a user’s SSH-agent is forwarded to load and unload shared libraries in /usr/lib* **on the user’s workstation**."  How does upgrading the `sshd` server exactly help fixing this **problem affecting the `ssh` client**?

Comment: Furthermore, on Debian, the agent forwarding is disabled by the default configuration: `ssh -G localhost | grep forwardagent` says `no`. This means that for this vulnerability to be effective one must have a certain configuration. That's probably why the patch is not backported in a hurry. Neither should anyone recklessly apply suggestions that a) does not fix the actual problem as the vulnerability isn't fully understood b) turn production systems into a state where the updates from the repositories aren't patching the running version anymore.

Comment: @EsaJokinen Another interesting question would be: When will a distribution like Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) get OpenSSH version 9.4p1 (or even higher)? The answer is likely to be "Never!" Using very old versions of certain packages, by itself, can be a security problem since corrections of other natures also occur, however people cannot keep their legacy systems and services stopped. Sorry, but I still haven't been able to find anything from a practical point of view that justifies your placements and your unproductive downvote... 

Comment: Stable distributions are designed for production environments that are required to guarantee long-term compatibility i.e. that the feature set of the software does not change suddenly. That's why they have fixed major versions of the software and backport the security fixes to older versions; giving **long-term support**. Frankly, new versions come with new bugs and vulnerabilities that could be as bad or even worse. That's why production servers use versions that have been tested rigorously & longer. The audience here has other goals than playing with the newest stuff. Hence the downvote.

Comment: @EsaJokinen 1# "The audience here has other goals than playing with the newest stuff." -> Speak for yourself.
2# "could be as bad or even worse" -> It is very unlikely that a mature community and a mature project like OpenSSH make mistakes of this nature, again... Speak for yourself.
3# I think what **you want is to impose your personal vision** and criticize the work of those who want to contribute. Be kind! 

Comment: I think @EsaJokinen has a very heavy point here: doing such tinkering in production server is a very bad practice — and as Esa just explained, it does not fix the problem, the problem is on the client side, not in the server.

Comment: Well, I bring an elegant and well-documented solution here that poses no risk to anyone who uses it. I can guarantee! For me, free software is a solution and not a bunch of innocuous criticism. Luckily, I'm not part of that current of thought. So I leave here my excellent contribution and your opinion to those who are interested. All the best! 

Comment: Well, fixing the vulnerability for any of the versions still affected would be called a contribution to the open source. Using a code repository to host a markdown formatted web page that suggests breaking a working distribution while leaving it vulnerable to the very vulnerability it promises to take care of... unlikely. It sadly belittles the work of those who actually keep the LTS distributions secure.

Comment: "leaving it vulnerable to the very vulnerability it promises to take care of" -> Source: @EsaJokinen opinion.

Comment: Source, e.g., [Qualys Security Advisory CVE-2023-38408](https://www.qualys.com/2023/07/19/cve-2023-38408/rce-openssh-forwarded-ssh-agent.txt), emphasis is mine: "Typically, a system administrator (Alice) runs ssh-agent **on her local
workstation**, connects to a remote server with ssh, and enables ssh-agent
forwarding with the `-A` or `ForwardAgent` option, thus **making her ssh-agent
(which is running on her local workstation) reachable from the remote
server**."

Comment: @EsaJokinen Man... You want to impose your point of view anyway... But you can't do the obvious... Proving in a practical way that there is a security flaw in my approach, it's just rhetoric. Go rest, sort out your things... You're really stuck, free software isn't that. For God's sake!‍

Comment: _"Well, I bring an elegant and well-documented solution here that poses no risk to anyone who uses it."_ - Compiling your own SSH server from source may break existing configuration (e.g. PAM integration, logging rules). It also means your won't get automatic security updates to SSH anymore. These are significant risks. Furthermore, as Esa has pointed out several times, the vulnerability is not in the SSH server, but the client. Updating the server does not help. That is not opinion, that is fact. I'm sorry, but despite your best intentions your advice is both unproductive and dangerous.

Comment: @marcelm There is a button called "Answer". Enter a **detailed and simple** answer to the problem. So, be happy and make many more happy! #heresatip 